# Quality of printing from free Flickr account

Tags: photos, flickr, printing

I have a free Flickr.com account. As you may know, the resolution of the images in the free account is limited to 1024 pixels. It is my understanding that Flickr stores the full resolution picture, but only allows the 1024px one to be displayed. I'm wondering whether I can use the print facility in Flickr to print photos in a large format at a satisfactory quality.

When I print a photo through Flickr's printing provider, is the high resolution picture sent to the provider, or just the 1024px one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest resolution versions will be sent to print.

Flickr will offer recommendations on the best size prints available based on the photo's size and resolution;

*see [What does "Not recommended for printing" mean?](http://www.flickr.com/help/printing/#125)*

You can over-ride this (not recommended) using the 'More options' link in the order pop-up;